# How can I remove a project from a Google Spreadsheet?

Tags: google-apps-script

I made a copy of a Google Apps Script project by mistake by choosing File > Make a copy... on Script Editor and since then every time I click Tools > Script Editor... on the Spreadsheet screen the project belongs to, I see a screen showing the two projects (original one and copied one) and I need to choose one to open the script editor. To be worse, the original script became unexecutable since I made the copy, I don't know if this is the cause of that though.

So, I'd like to remove the copy project from the Spreadsheet. How can I do that? I can't find any menu to remove project.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the ***"copy of"*** version of the script, click **File -> Delete Project...**  This will generate a confirmation box.  Click the **Delete** button to confirm that you would like to delete the project.  This should leave your original as the only associated script.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I can't find it on my screen maybe because the copy was done by another person. I'll make him do that. Thank you so much!